# How i can Send Auto sms in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

I want to send SMS automatically in my app , How can i do it in swift ? I use MFMessageComposeViewController to send SMS but when i clicked button , It go to SMS page and ask me to send SMS, how it can do automatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

iOS doesn't support sending SMS. It only support `MFMessageComposeViewController` to show SMS page.

If you want to send SMS , you need to use other service like

- https://www.twilio.com/sms
- https://docs.fabric.io/ios/digits/digits.html

Comment: This is the correct answer. Apple specifically prevents you from sending SMS messages programmatically. You have to display a compose message dialog. You would need a server to send the messages on your behalf, and then I don't think you could have the messages originate from the user's phone number.